# Firebase like system not working properly

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made some easy like system since I didn't know the better solution for this. However the problem is that if user likes something for the first time, it sets the value to `false` instead of `true` and I can't seem to find bug in my code. It seems to work only if I double tap on button.

Like this I check if value is false, make button label "like" else dislike inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
databaseRef.child("postLikes").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.value as? Bool == true{
                print("has liked")
                cell.likeButton.setTitle("Dislike", for: .normal)
            }else{

                print("hasn't liked")
                cell.likeButton.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)
            }
        })
```

And that is the function I call when pressing button:

```
func like(sender: UIButton){
        let section = 0
        let row = sender.tag
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        let cell: FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
        if cell.likeButton.titleLabel?.text == "Like"{
        self.databaseRef.child("postLikes").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Bool

            if (value == nil) {
                value = false
            }
            currentData.value = true
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        })

        self.databaseRef.child("posts").child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).child("likes").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int

            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        })

        }else{
            self.databaseRef.child("posts").child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).child("likes").runTransactionBlock({
                (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                var value = currentData.value as? Int

                if (value == nil) {
                    value = 0
                }
                currentData.value = value! - 1
                cell.likeButton.titleLabel?.text = "Like"
                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        })
            self.databaseRef.child("postLikes").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).runTransactionBlock({
                (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                var value = currentData.value as? Bool

                if (value == nil) {
                    value = false
                }
                currentData.value = false
                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        })
        }
    }
```

What should cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to check if problem persist than if you change this line

```
if snapshot.value as? Bool == true {}
```

with this

```
if snapshot.value as? Bool != true{
            print("has liked")
            cell.likeButton.setTitle("Dislike", for: .normal)
} else { ... }
```

But the problem seems in this part

```
  if cell.likeButton.titleLabel?.text == "Like"{
    self.databaseRef.child("postLikes").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(postsArray[indexPath.row].key).runTransactionBlock({
        (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
        var value = currentData.value as? Bool

        if (value == nil) {
            value = false
        }




        currentData.value = true // <-- should be false

        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

    })
```

Comment: It is not working even like this which is expected since It is just opposite what I were doing since `!= true` `==` `false` isn't it? :D It works same. Only works if I click double. And in your answer you logic is wrong. If he hasn't liked the title should be "Like" else "Dislike" not opposite

Comment: It was for check up if your backend logic is true